Recovering bitlocker data block from deleted partition
Okay, here's my situation -

one of my colleague's laptop got broken windows and needed to recover some data from it.
the support technician attempted to directly access the data but couldn't because it's bitlocker encrypted through TPM.
so what he did is delete the partition table and try to get data through EaseUs data recovery.
he couldn't because it doesn't matter whether there's partition table or not, the data's still locked.
what EaseUs recover instead is a single 'winre.wim' file which has the exact file size of the bitlocker partition.
I can't seem to read or mount this wim file with DISM at all. It shows the file is in incorrect format.

So, I'm hoping may be this file is the encrypted block data image that EaseUs sees and that I can somehow rebuild the partition with this data block and mount it on the original laptop so that it will decrypt automatically with old TPM key.
Anyone has any experience with the scenario?

Does your colleague know the Bitlocker key, or at least the admin account password (the keys are usually derived from such,) because then you can simply decrypt the data with said key: bitlocker uses AES 128 or 256 bit encryption.

WinRE.wim isn’t your data.

They key should be in the TPM chip. The technician kind of messed up when he's trying to recover data from it. The windows was booting into recovery environment because of some system file corruption. He should have at least taken the full disk image backup, before doing something dangerous. At this point, I'm not hoping much anymore.
@Ramhound, that's what I thought as well. It's just a common name for recovery image. Just grasping at straws.. Any idea on why this file can't be read by DISM at all?

@NayMin - I don’t have access to the DISM error message. If it was on the system volume that was encrypted. That would be one reason
